# ionic stop and remove devices after run

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

How to remove old runs in ionic? I am using this line to see my app in browser

```
ionic cordova run browser -l -p 8001
```

But the app doesnt live reload when i update my code and more importantly it always assign new port in each run and the app is still running on the old port? I run this command 5 times and it always create new instance on new port (8001 - 8006) at this moment. **How do i remove the old runs and always use just one port?**

I am using ionic 3.19.0 and developing app for iOS and android. I liked the `ionic serve` command to see my progress with live reload and debugging my code. But i started using `import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';` that needs the cordova support.

Comment: How are you "closing" the old instances that are running?

Comment: just with CTRL + C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can replicate the issue you are describing, also with just using `ionic cordova run browser`. It does not happen when using `cordova run browser` directly, but this is missing the Ionic build step and livereload so might not be your solution.

This seems to be a bug with Ionic CLI, probably caused by it swallowing the `Terminate batch job (Y/N)?` prompt you get with `cordova run` but not `ionic cordova run`.

I reported this as an issue for Ionic CLI:
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2916

To "reset" the port number usage you can once run `cordova run browser` and kill it with Ctrl + C - the next run of `ionic cordova run browser ...` will then get port 8000 again.

Comment: THX for response, i am glad i am not the only one with the bug, this command `cordova run browser` works ok and i can terminate it with CTRL + C, but is there some easy way to remove the old runs? I solved my issue with `sudo pkill -f /usr/local/bin/cordova run browser` though

Comment: Using `cordova run browser` once and then stopping it with Ctrl + C kills all running processes from before for me. Next time I run `ionic cordova run browser` I get port 8000 again.